# How to execute an FTP upload task after assembly:single in Maven?

Tags: java, maven, ftp

I'm using the `pom.xml` file shown below to build a certain JAR file (`myproduct-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar`) using `mvn assembly:single`.

I want to be able to upload that file via FTP as described in [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15884708/maven-deployment-with-ftp-uploading-i-want-to-upload-just-the-war-file-but-is-u).

I added the following code part in order to be able to do the upload using `mvn install:install`:

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.7</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>install</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>install</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <target>
            <property name="file_name" value="myproduct-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar" />
            <ant antfile="${basedir}/build.xml">
                <target name="upload" />
            </ant>
        </target>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

I get the error `Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:2.3.1:install (default-cli) on project ...: The packaging for this project did not assign a file to the build artifact -> [Help 1]`.

How can I upload the file generated by `mvn assembly:single` via FTP (either using a separate call, or right after the `myproduct-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar` has been generated) ?

Here's the `pom.xml` file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
    <artifactId>myproduct</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>bukkit-repo</id>
            <url>http://repo.bukkit.org/content/groups/public/</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>maven-restlet</id>
            <name>Public online Restlet repository</name>
            <url>http://maven.restlet.com</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <dependencies>
        [...]
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.7</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>install</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>install</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <target>
                        <property name="file_name" value="myproduct-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar" />
                        <ant antfile="${basedir}/build.xml">
                            <target name="upload" />
                        </ant>
                    </target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this using [`wagon-maven-plugin`](http://maven.apache.org/wagon/) and its [`upload-single`](http://www.mojohaus.org/wagon-maven-plugin/upload-single-mojo.html) goal.

In your Maven settings, you need to add a [server declaration](https://maven.apache.org/settings.html#Servers), which will declare the credentials to connect to your FTP server:

```xml
<server>
  <id>my-server-id</id>
  <username>my-user-name</username>
  <password>my-password</password>
</server>
```

And then you need to configure the plugin to use this server to upload the file. Wagon works with several providers that are added through extensions: in this case we need to add `wagon-ftp` provider.

```xml
<project>
  [...]
  <build>
    [...]
    <extensions>
      <extension>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.wagon</groupId>
        <artifactId>wagon-ftp</artifactId>
        <version>2.10</version>
      </extension>
    </extensions>
    [...]
    <plugins>
     <plugin>
      <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
      <artifactId>wagon-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>1.0</version>
      <executions>
        <execution>
          <id>upload-assembly</id>
          <phase>install</phase>
          <goals>
            <goal>upload-single</goal>
          </goals>
          <configuration>
            <serverId>my-server-id</serverId> <!-- references the server declaration -->
            <fromFile>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}-${project.version}-jar-with-dependencies.jar</fromFile>
            <url>ftp://your.remote.host/</url>
            <toFile>remote.file</toFile>
          </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
     </plugins>
    </build>
    [...]
</project>
```

In this example, the Wagone execution is bound to the `install` phase so to run it, you need to launch Maven with `mvn clean install`. You may want to bind it to another phase depending on your requirement.

Comment: @DmitriPisarenko Yes, sorry, `fromDir` needed to be `fromFile`. What did you specify for the `url`?

Comment: @DmitriPisarenko it's supposed to be `toFile`, not `toDir`.

Comment: @DmitriPisarenko Did you modify your Maven settings? How are you running Maven?

Comment: @DmitriPisarenko Yes you should not run it like that. Change the phase to `install` (it was `deploy`) and run `mvn clean install`.

Comment: Thanks. The correct command (which creates JAR with dependencies) is `mvn clean assembly:single install`.